# Issues removing stake from 0x

Tags: 0x, staking

When on the 0x website in the staking portion, I can see all my data.
When I click the remove button, I get the modal popup asking if I'm sure.
I click the "I understand, remove my stake" button and nothing happens.
What's the issue? my hw wallet is connected through metamask.

Seems related to:
https://www.reddit.com/r/0xProject/comments/ql308v/problem_unstaking_error_execution_reverted/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

But not identical.

Can some from 0x please respond or fix?

Comment: I am having the same problem. Using Metamask, nothing happens after I hit remove and the message comes up and I hit "i understand, remove my stake". There is no reaction in Metamask and the rewards are not released. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

we are sorry you are experiencing issues in unstaking.
Since you have pointed out to that reddit post, have you tried using the solution indicated there?

> I've solved the issue now — I'm using the Coinbase wallet app. I
> solved this by "Clearing Pending Transaction" in the settings. And
> also by logging out and then back in again. I think it was the sign
> out that actually solved the problem. Hopefully this helps someone
> else.

If you're using Coinbase Wallet, which wallet are you using?
Sometimes with fluctuations in gas prices, we have observed that the gas sent back to the wallet can cause estimates to go beyond the necessary. We are still investigating the issue.

In the meantime, may I ask you if you have enough ETH to pay your transaction? Use this as a reference to know how much gas you might need to remove stake, better to add a 20-30% buffer to that.
https://dune.xyz/queries/19394/39637

If you have enough ETH, my best suggestion in the meantime is to try this again.

Let us know if you've solved your issue